# create an order on Prestashop API : error with module name

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to create an order through the Prestashop API (v1.6.1.13). I havn't written any module, my goal is just to use its API without installing anything on the prestashop.

Creating an order requires a **module** name. If I leave it blank I get the error:

> Validation error: "Property Order->module is empty"

If I write a fake name it says :

> Validation error: "Property Order->module is not valid"

What should I do ? While I have the same issue with the **payment** field ?

Here is what I'm sending :

```
<prestashop>
<order>
  <id_address_delivery>1299</id_address_delivery>
  <id_address_invoice>1300</id_address_invoice>
  <id_cart>218</id_cart>
  <id_currency>1</id_currency>
  <id_lang>2</id_lang>
  <id_customer>214</id_customer>
  <id_carrier>2</id_carrier>
  <current_state>2</current_state>
  <module></module>
  <invoice_number>0</invoice_number>
  <delivery_number>0</delivery_number>
  <valid>1</valid>
  <date_add>2017-06-27 23:00:46</date_add>
  <date_upd>2017-06-28 11:50:13</date_upd>
  <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
  <id_shop>1</id_shop
  <payment>MyPayment</payment>
  <recyclable>0</recyclable>
  <gift>0</gift>
  <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
  <total_discounts>0</total_discounts>
  <total_discounts_tax_incl>0</total_discounts_tax_incl>
  <total_discounts_tax_excl>0</total_discounts_tax_excl>
  <total_paid>27</total_paid>
  <total_paid_tax_incl>27</total_paid_tax_incl>
  <total_paid_tax_excl>27</total_paid_tax_excl>
  <total_paid_real>27</total_paid_real>
  <total_products>27</total_products>
  <total_products_wt>27</total_products_wt>
  <total_shipping>0</total_shipping>
  <total_shipping_tax_incl>0</total_shipping_tax_incl>
  <total_shipping_tax_excl>0</total_shipping_tax_excl>
  <carrier_tax_rate>0</carrier_tax_rate>
  <total_wrapping>0</total_wrapping>
  <total_wrapping_tax_incl>0</total_wrapping_tax_incl>
  <total_wrapping_tax_excl>0</total_wrapping_tax_excl>
  <conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
  <reference>170627369</reference>
  <associations>
    <order_rows>
      <order_row>
        <product_id>2</product_id>
        <product_attribute_id>7</product_attribute_id>
        <product_quantity>2</product_quantity>
        <product_name>Blouse</product_name>
        <product_reference>demo_2</product_reference>
        <product_ean13>0</product_ean13>
        <product_price>27</product_price>
        <unit_price_tax_incl>27</unit_price_tax_incl>
        <unit_price_tax_excl>27</unit_price_tax_excl>
      </order_row>
    </order_rows>
  </associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

Any help/idea would be greatly appreciate, thanks !

Comment: If I send <module>Bankwire</module> it throws an exception a little bit later : "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function validateOrder() on boolean". I assume it's due to the **payment** field which is not valid.

What is the good process to create an order with any Prestashop API ?

Comment: Hi Toine Seiter, have you looked to [this](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/228545-webservice-api-how-to-create-a-full-order-customer-cart-and-order/)? I guess it should be a great point to start. However I suppose you have to create the cart first, retrieve the ID and then create the order.

The `payment` field can be 'Cash on delivery' that is the name, and the `module` should be the technical name of the module `cashondelivery` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I have a shipping address, a billing one, a customer and a cart. I tried with the module="cashindelivery" and payment="Cash on delivery" but it fails on the validateOrder().

Comment: Here is my error : `Call to a member function validateOrder() on boolean in /data/www/azureshop/releases/20170614134354Z/prestashop/classes/order/Order.php:1577`

Comment: Mmmm... I guess that the Order class can't instantiate the correct module, so it tries to call the `validateOrder` method on a boolean var... You have to do some debug on that line of the Order class :)

Comment: great... thank you

Answer (score 2):

After some debug steps in the payment module I found the solution.
The `module` should be a valid module name (I use "bankwire") and `payment` can be wathever you want (the name of the external source for example).

I was testing an address which country was disabled... Enabling the country fix the issue.

What a pity Prestashop doesn't respond the reason on the API call... Even if activating the DEV mode of prestashop and DEBUG of the PaymentModule.

Thanks for your help sarcom !

Comment: I'm glad that you have solved :). You're welcome Toine ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need Enable the payment options(like payment by check) in prestashop admin side and then need to add the module with prefix ps_moduleName without any space.
I did like this,
$xml->order->module= "ps_".strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $order_data['payment_method']));
You can try this if there is any error or If you have any better solution then it me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Finally we abandonned the Prestashop API which is a nightmare and we developped a custom Prestashop module that expose a custom API